# Failed to install PyZMQ 13.1 for PyPy 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: pip, pypy, pyzmq

I use pip install as root. Everything works with CPython because it doesn't use the cffi backend. With PyPy I get the following error:

```
ImportError: PyZMQ CFFI backend couldn't find zeromq: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  
'/********/site-packages/zmq/cffi_core/__pycache__/_cffi__g5368a726x67d4e236.c'
```

The '/********/site-packages/zmq/cffi_core/ directory exists and contains the following .py files(and correponding .pyc):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 7.8K Jul 16 17:29 _cffi.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  406 Jul 16 17:29 constants.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 2.2K Jul 16 17:29 context.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  915 Jul 16 17:29 devices.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  551 Jul 16 17:29 error.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1000 Jul 16 17:29 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1.7K Jul 16 17:29 message.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 2.1K Jul 16 17:29 _poll.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 6.8K Jul 16 17:29 socket.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1.1K Jul 16 17:29 stopwatch.py
```

But, there is no `__pycache__` directory.

By poking around the cffi Python files (in particular verifier.py) I found that it can't find the following *cffi*_g5368a726x67d4e236.pypy-20.so. I couldn't find it anywhere either. I guess it is not built for some reason, but I didn't see any errors during pip install.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Maybe setup.py is bogus and doesn't build the .so?  If so, we have a problem, because the directory is installed as `root` but you're likey to run `pypy` as a normal user.  Try to create the missing .so by running a `sudo pypy` in which you do `import zmq`.

Comment: There is no compilation to do at install time for PyPy (CFFI does all of the compilation at runtime).

Comment: That's correct. I had some mess with different Python versions, symlinks, virtual environments, etc. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @minrk: you are wrong: modules using CFFI that are installed with setup.py are compiled at install-time (provided it was configured this way, which is recommended).

Comment: That is not true in pyzmq.

Comment: I should clarify - no compilation happens during setup of pyzmq on PyPy, that doesn't mean it *shouldn't*.

Comment: Then it might be a bug in the setup.py of pyzmq.  See: https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.7/#distributing-modules-using-cffi